# Simple question about inequality involving eigenvalue of a matrix and a scaled version of that matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $x$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $A^*=\sum_1^{i=n} x_ix_i^T$ and $A=\sum_1^{i=n} a_ix_ix_i^T$ for $a_1>a_2>\cdots>a_n$  for $i<j$ where the second summand is called $A^*$.

Is it true that
$$a_d\lambda_k(A^*) \le \lambda_k(A)\le a_1 \lambda_k(A^*),$$ where $\lambda_k(\cdot)$ is the $k$-th nonzero eigenvalue?

Comment: What is $X_i$? $A^*$ and $A$ have different numbers of terms in summation?

Comment: It is fixed. Sorry for the typos.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ vectors mutually orthogonal?

Comment: I also assume that in your inequality you want $a_n$ and not $a_d$.

Comment: I think you mean each $x_i$ is a vector, not just $x$ (which would imply that the $x_i$'s are its components and hence just numbers). Then, you refer to $A^*$ as the *second* summand (I think you mean sum), but write the equations so that its the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the additional assumption that $d\ge n$ and the vectors $x_i$ are non-zero and mutually orthogonal, then the claim is true. I.e. $x_i\ne0$ for all $i$, $x_i^Tx_j=0$ for all $i\ne j$.

Let $A^*=\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T$ and $A=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_ix_i^T$.

The vector $x_i$ is a eigenvector to both $A$ and $A^*$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i(A^*) = \|x_i\|^{-2}$ and $\lambda_i(A) = a_i\|x_i\|^{-2}$. Hence
$$
a_d\lambda_i(A^*)\le \lambda_i(A)\le a_1\lambda_i(A^*),
$$
where $a_1$ and $a_d$ are the largest and smallest of the coefficients $a_i$.

The eigenvalues $n+1\dots d$ are all zero, $\lambda_i(A)=\lambda_i(A^*)=0$ for $i=n+1\dots d$.